# save_post + insert_post = infinite loop

Tags: loop, wp-insert-post, save-post

I'm trying to automatically create a new post when a post containing a certain custom field is saved - hooking an insert_post function into save_post.

This generates an infinite loop.

I found some answers to this problem, suggesting I should check the post type before inserting.

However, the following code still gives an infinite loop, any ideas?

```
add_action('save_post', 'createGallery');

function createGallery () {
    global $post;
    if ( $post->post_type == 'activity' ) {
        $gallerypost = array(
            'post_content' => 'the text of the post',
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'post_title' => 'Photo album', 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'post_author' => 1);  
        wp_insert_post( $gallerypost );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the first time you go round the loop `$post` is the current post. But the second time you go around the loop, $post has not changed. The same thing happens the 3rd, 4th, 5th, etc

Because the $post variable is the current post of that page, not the post you've just saved/inserted, the loops if statement will always be true, and an infinite loop entails. Instead of checking the `$post` variable, you should check the ID of the post that is being saved. If we look at the call that executes the action `save_post`:

```
do_action('save_post', $post_ID, $post);
```

We now see that save_post has parameters!! So if we indicate when adding that the function accepts 1 parameters:

```
add_action('save_post', 'createGallery',1,1);
```

Then add the post ID parameter and use that instead:

```
function createGallery ($post_ID) {
    if ( get_post_type($post_ID) == 'activity' ) {
        $gallerypost = array(
            'post_content' => 'the text of the post',
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'post_title' => 'Photo album', 
            'post_type' => 'post', 
            'post_author' => 1);  
        wp_insert_post( $gallerypost );
    }
}
```

Then your infinite loop should be gone! If it isn't then you've made a considerable leap towards making your code more accurate since you are now working on the correct data.

I would warn that changing `'post_type' => 'post',` to `'post_type' => 'activity',` would reintroduce the infinite loop.

Comment: That worked like a charm, thanks for the detailed explanation - you're my hero for today!