# wp_insert_post wrong post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, filters, wp-insert-post, recursive

Much like [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/34567/save-post-insert-post-infinite-loop), I'm having trouble with wp_insert_post causing recursive post adding. I do, however, have implemented a page type check - the problem is the inserted post always gets added as the same type, no matter the type specified.

```
function create_auto_post($post_ID) {
    if (get_post_type($post_ID) != 'manually-published') return;

    $post_ID = wp_insert_post(
            array(
                'post_status'       =>  'publish',
                'post_type'         =>  'automatically-published'
            )
        );
}

add_filter( 'save_post', 'create_auto_post', 1, 1);
```

The inserted post is of type manually-published, therefore triggering a recursive insertion of post until database time out. What am I doing wrong?

Note: I have tried using the 'publish_manually-published' action for the filter, the problem is the same - post gets added as 'manually-published' instead of 'automatically-published'.

Comment: is this your full function code?

Comment: @inarilo it's not the full planned code, but it's where i am getting stuck already.

Comment: maybe it's because you are using add_filter instead of add_action? your code looks fine to me.

Comment: a really fair point and one i can't believe i missed. will test and report if it works, if yes please submit as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your code creates a post if the created post is not `manually-published`, but the new post is `automatically-published`, and those don't match. Your conditional is not explicit enough and eneds to skip the scenario when your inserted post is inserted to prevent an infinite loop

Instead of:

```
function create_auto_post($post_ID) {
    if (get_post_type($post_ID) != 'manually-published') return;
```

Consider:

```
function create_auto_post( $post_ID, $post ) {
    if ( in_array( $post->post_type, [ 'manually-published', 'automatically-published' ] ) {
        return;
    }
```

Further notes:

- This isn't a filter it's actually an action, use `add_action` instead
- The `save_post` action passes the post object as a second parameter, it's better to use that
- You'll need to indicate that this function takes 2 not 1 parameter for this to work
- Your original code assumes all posts will be of 2 post types, but you forget that images/attachments are also a post type, as are menu items in nav menus, and many other things that other plugins add. Right now it's going to create `automatically-published` posts for all your menu items and attachments, as well as other things you might not have considered

Comment: hi, thanks for the help! i have some questions:

1. what's the difference between get_post_type($post_ID) and $post->post_type? is $post_ID not the ID of $post? why is using $post better? the answer in the question i linked states that the $post object is not updated and specifically recommends using $post_ID in its stead.

2. if you check closer, you'll see i am returning the function for posts that are NOT of type 'manually-published', i.e. the following code should only get executed for posts of type 'manually-published'. am i missing something here?

Comment: 1. they do the same thing, but the one I used is more direct, and I prefer to be explicit, afterall `get_post_type` is doing the same thing internally so why not cut out the middle man? But if you prefer the other method feel free

Comment: 2. Sure, but that's a very wide net you're casting, now automatically published posts are going to get created for everything, including automatically created posts, which will trigger the hook, which will create an automatically published post, which will trigger the hook, which will create an automatic... etc etc so `automatically-published` needs to be excluded. I do have to wonder why this is all being done though, at a minimum the number of posts is doubled

Comment: 1. thanks for the clarification!
2. the post types provided are placeholders. in practice, i want to create new posts only when a certain type of post is created, and even then with additional checks in place. the 'manually-created' post type here is not equivalent to the 'post' type.

Comment: that complicates things, now it's impossible to know the actual flow of things and diagnose because you've hidden the post types you're actually using. Eitherway the crux of the problem is that `wp_insert_post` fires the `save_post` hook, and you're calling `wp_insert_post` on that hook, creating an infinite loop

Comment: the post types are custom post types, as i've said a few times before- the only thing "hidden" is their actual name, which has no effect on this whatsoever. and yes, that is precisely what i was asking - why is my check `if (get_post_type($post_ID) != 'manually-published') return;` not sufficient to prevent the rest of the function firing for any post.

Comment: It's not clear how many custom post types you have, or the context. It might be that your entire approach can be replaced with a super simple solution, and because you've hidden the context, it's slightly ambiguous how it's supposed to work, especially when 'manually-published' is divorced from that explanation. Coupled with the fact this is an XY problem where instead of asking how to do what you need it to do, you asked how to fix the solution to the problem with the solution to the problem you originally had

Comment: For example, because I don't know how many custom post types and what they are, this becomes a problem as some answers that could be given might not apply. E.g. if the task is to create a single post X when a post of type Y is created, then I can give an answer, but that would fall apart if it needs to happen on multiple post types. Keep in mind that nowhere in your question do you actually describe what's supposed to happen in a self contained paragraph, everything is in the context of the problem, which makes it difficult to parse what it's supposed to do

Comment: I don't understand what was vague about my question. It was tagged as custom post types, the code provided exactly the one I was using, and the only thing changed the names of the two specific custom post types, since their original names were not in English. You misunderstood the names of the custom post types as me describing their origin. My question was specifically: why is the new post I am creating not of the specified post type?

Comment: I thought it was why do I get infinite recursion with this conditional? I still don't know what the original purpose of the code is context is super super important. If I knew that I could write a new piece of code from scratch that works then compare and contrast, but I can't, no context, I don't know what the code is supposed to do, all I know is that it's misbehaving in a particular way. It's super unhelpful

Comment: yes, my bad - it's been a while since i've worked on this problem and got slightly confused. obviously the conditional didn't catch it because the post type is not correct. the original purpose of the code is to created a post of type 'automatically-published' whenever a post of type 'manually-published' is saved. the problem is the new post is of type 'manually-published' instead of 'automatically-published'. sorry if this wasn't obvious enough. hope it's clear enough now.